# Angular2 Service reinstantiated when changing route

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a service that loads asynchronously the gmaps api. When I load it, I save in that service a property name "isGoogleMapLibraryLoaded" setted to true.

When I go to another route (without refreshing of course) and go back to previous, the service gets reinstantiated and I lost the "isGoogleMapLibraryLoaded" property.

How can I set properties in a service that persists when switching between routes?

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDvo543530SU_xsZLvZ6SjTFbt1FPW9FI';
const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&callback=__onGoogleMapLoaded`;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapService {
  /**
   * Google maps loading status (althought loading is not completed)
   */
  private isGoogleMapLibraryLoaded: Boolean = false;
  constructor(){
  }

  getNewMapInstance(element, props){
    console.log(this.isGoogleMapLibraryLoaded);
    this._loading().then(() => {
      return new google.maps.Map(element, props);
    });
  }

  private _loading(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(!this.isGoogleMapLibraryLoaded){
        this.isGoogleMapLibraryLoaded = true;

          resolve();

      }else{
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I added the service in bootstrap and I'm injecting it in component constructor

constructor(private mapService: GoogleMapService){}

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.googleMapInstance = this.mapService.getNewMapInstance(this.googleMapWrapperElement.nativeElement, {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on where you provide the service. If you provide it at the root component, the instance will exist as long as the root component (equals as long as your Angular application is running).

If you provide it at your routed component, it will be discarded as soon as the component is removed.